# "Odd number of hash elements" when declaring MooseX::ClassAttribute

Tags: perl, moose, class-attribute

On OSX 'Mavericks', this:

```
package FOO;    
use Moose;
use MooseX::ClassAttribute;
class_has 'BAR' => ( is => 'rw' );
```

... checks clean per 'perl -c':

> FOO.pm syntax OK

... but gives this error if I run it simply with 'perl FOO.pm':

> Odd number of elements in hash assignment at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.16/MooseX/ClassAttribute.pm line 37.
>   Can't use string ("file") as a HASH ref while "strict refs" in use at /Library/Perl/5.16/darwin-thread-multi-2level/Moose/Meta/Attribute.pm line 71.

I've tried every way I can to figure out what's going on here, but I'm stumped. Is there something else I have to 'use' or declare first? (This is the smallest test case I could come up with, but the error happens whenever I use class_has() in a module.)

Comment: I haven't really done any work with Moose, but would you want to include your perl module in a program and run that? I don't think you're supposed to be doing `perl FOO.pm` but rather `perl some_program.pl` that has `use FOO.pm` in it.

Comment: Try running `moose-outdated` at the command line.  You may have an obsolete & incompatible module hanging around.

Comment: I've tested your SSCCE and it works fine; exactly as expected.  I think @cjm is on the right track; something's out of date, broken, or incompletely installed in your toolchain.

Comment: @cjm, you're right. I had to re-install about a half-dozen MooseX modules, then it ran smoothly. Now if only the actual application would, but that's another story :)

Comment: @amp108: Please would you write up a solution and accept it. Thanks.

Comment: On non-production systems `perl`s, I like to do a `cpan-outdated | cpanm -v` every now and then. See [my blog post](http://blog.nu42.com/2012/05/updating-all-outdated-perl-modules.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get strange errors from a module that uses Moose, the first thing to do is run the `moose-outdated` script at the command line.  You probably have an outdated MooseX module that's not compatible with the installed version of Moose.

You should run `moose-outdated` every time you upgrade Moose, but it's easy to forget, especially when Moose was upgraded because it's one of the dependencies of some other module you're installing.